# How to quantise an image with an 8x8 matrix using blockproc in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The idea comes from jpeg compression where you apply a quantisation matrix (8x8) blockwise to a (cosine-transformed) image.

```
funQY = @(block_struct) (block_struct.data)./quantY;
QY = blockproc(dctY, [8 8], funQY);
```

dctY is an 2D matrix representing the luminance of a picture (2856x4290). quantY is the corresponding quantisation matrix (8x8).

Error message says that the matrix dimensions do not agree. Doesn't block_struct.data represent a 8x8 block from dctY? If so, why can't it be devided by a 8x8 matrix? What is my mistake here?

Comment: I suspect it's because `4290` is not an even multiple of 8.

Comment: Could you share the whole script and the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@beaker noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38029051/how-to-quantise-an-image-with-an-8x8-matrix-using-blockproc-in-matlab#comment63499678_38029051), the reason is that your image size is not divisible with the size of your blocks. Here's a simple example where we check the size of each block passed to the function in `blockproc`:

```
dctY = rand(24,34); % first dim is divisible, second is not
funtmp = @(block_struct) size(block_struct.data);
blockproc(dctY,[8 8],funtmp)
```

This returns

```
ans =

     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     2
     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     2
     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     2
```

As you can see on the rightmost side, the last block in each block row is a partial one with size `[8, 2]`.

You can use [the `PadPartialBlocks` option of `blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html#br_lk2d-1):

```
'PadPartialBlocks'  A logical scalar.  When set to true, blockproc will
                    pad partial blocks to make them full-sized (M-by-N)
                    blocks.  Partial blocks arise when the image size
                    is not exactly divisible by the block size.  If
                    they exist, partial blocks will lie along the right
                    and bottom edge of the image.  The default is
                    false, meaning the partial blocks are not padded,
                    but processed as-is.

                    blockproc uses zeros to pad partial blocks when
                    necessary.
```

This results in

```
>> blockproc(dctY,[8 8],funtmp,'padpartialblocks',true)

ans =

     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
```

Depending on your application, you might be better off with trimming off the last partial block, rather than padding with a given value. You can optionally perform this using the `TrimBorder` and `BorderSize` options, these will trim off pixels symmetrically.

Comment: Problem solved by cutting the images by a couple of pixels to something dividable by 8. Thanks!